# Select the Object with linq that best fit the Query strings

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have a situation where I am trying to link two different data source together. see the code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string url = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode("yql");
    HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
    var response = cl.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);
    var ids = from p in json["p"]
              from span in p["span"]
              where (string)span["content"] == "01/19/2017"
              select (string)span["genre"];


}
```

this is what the JSON looks likeenter code here

please note this JSON is a little different from what you will get from yql as I shorten it removing bits I don't need. this is the
link to the full JSON - https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fthemoviedb.org%2Fsearch%2Fmovie%3Fquery%3Dsplit%22%20%20AND%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22info%22%5D'&format=json&callback=

I want to be able to query the JSON and select the object that best match this:

```
string year = "2017";
string genre = "Drama, Thriller, Action";
string title = "split"
```

or

```
public class Movie{
public   string year {get; set;}
public   string title {get; set;}
public   Genre genre{get; set;}
}
```

then

```
List<Movie> _movie = new List<Movie>()
_movie.add(new Movie{year = 2017, title=split, genre[]=Thriller, Drama, Action})
```

from the query object and the JSON that from yql... the result should be split 01/19/2017

Comment: I think you mean JSON and not Jason. JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation. I could be wrong, and you actual mean Jason, but I have never heard of if :)

Comment: Its a typo thanks to spell heck. I meant JSON

Comment: "this is what the Jason looks likeenter code here"   Please edit the question and insert the JSON you're talking about.

Comment: I am not on my pc at the moment but if you copy the link I included into your browser you will get the JSON.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "best fit"?

Comment: By best fit I mean for instance A[red, yellow, green, blue] and B[black, pink, purple, cyan] which of A and B is more similar to C[Yellow, Green, Gray, Cyan]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string[] Genre { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fthemoviedb.org%2Fsearch%2Fmovie%3Fquery%3Dsplit%22%20%20AND%20xpath%3D%27%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22info%22%5D%27&format=json&callback=");
        HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
        var response = cl.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);

        var movies = new List<Movie>();

        foreach (var pchild in json["query"]["results"]["div"])
        {
            // title
            var title = pchild["p"][0]["a"]["title"];
            var titleStr = title != null ? title.Value<string>() : string.Empty;

            // year
            var releaseDate = pchild["p"][1]["span"][0]["content"];
            string releaseYear = string.Empty;

            DateTime temp;
            if (releaseDate != null
                && DateTime.TryParse(releaseDate.Value<string>(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out temp))
            {
                releaseYear = temp.Year.ToString();
            }

            // genres
            var genre = pchild["p"][1]["span"][1]["content"];
            var genreArr = genre != null
                            ? genre.Value<string>()
                                .Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Select(st => st.Trim())
                                .ToArray()
                            : new string[0];

            movies.Add(
                new Movie
                {
                    Title = titleStr,
                    Year = releaseYear,
                    Genre = genreArr
                });
        }


        // searching for the best match
        string titleFilter = "Split";
        string yearFilter = "2017";
        var genreFilter = new string[] { "Drama", "Thriller", "Action" };

        var bestMatches = movies
                            .OrderByDescending(m => m.Title == titleFilter)
                            .ThenByDescending(m => m.Year == yearFilter)
                            .ThenByDescending(m => m.Genre.Intersect(genreFilter).Count());

        // the best match
        var bestMatch = bestMatches.First();
        Console.WriteLine(bestMatch.Title);
        Console.WriteLine(bestMatch.Year);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", bestMatch.Genre));


        // all the movies already ordered
        //foreach (var movie in bestMatches)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(movie.Title);
        //    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", movie.Genre));
        //    Console.WriteLine(movie.Year);
        //    Console.WriteLine();
        //}

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Input:

```
string titleFilter = "Split";  
string yearFilter = "2017";  
var genreFilter = new string[] { "Drama", "Thriller", "Action" };
```

Best match:

```
Split    
2017    
Drama,Horror,Thriller
```

Note that you may have several movies with the same matches.
Input:

```
string titleFilter = "Split";
string yearFilter = "2016";
var genreFilter = new string[] { "Drama", "Thriller", "Action" };
```

Best matches (you can uncomment the last part of code to see all the movies ordered):

```
Split  
Fantasy,Drama  
2016  

Split  
Drama  
2016
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto... I actually figured it out using linq I think your logic is short-hand compared to mine. I will refactor my code. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: hello Pedro, I found a bug on your pattern... if the Json object is exactly one your code crashes. see what I mean with this link - https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.themoviedb.org%2Fsearch%2Fmovie%3Fquery%3DResident%2BEvil:%2BThe%2BFinal%2BChapter'%20AND%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22info%22%5D'&format=json&callback= and to get around it you have to remove the for each loop and access the value direct but doing that will only give you one object in a case you have more than one objects.

Comment: I can not access to this url. I have an Query Syntax error. Can you please verify the url?

Comment: go to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995509/foreach-and-json-linq-query-is-it-a-bug-or-i-dont-understand?noredirect=1