# Foreach and Json/Linq query, is it a bug or i dont understand?

Tags: c#, json, linq, loops

[the link to Json objects greater than one](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.themoviedb.org%2Fsearch%2Fmovie%3Fquery%3DMonster%2BTrucks'%20AND%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22info%22%5D'&format=json&callback=)

when I try to obtain values with an array of objects in a Json file I get through with no problem using this code.

```
string _url = WebUtility.UrlDecode("https%3A%2F%2Fquery.yahooapis.com%2Fv1%2Fpublic%2Fyql%3Fq%3DSELECT%2520%2A%2520FROM%2520html%2520WHERE%2520url%253D%27https%253A%252F%252Fwww.themoviedb.org%252Fsearch%252Fmovie%253Fquery%253D"+titleStg+"%27%2520AND%2520xpath%253D%27%252F%252Fdiv%255B%2540class%253D%2522info%2522%255D%27%26format%3Djson%26callback%3D");
                   HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
        var response = cl.GetStringAsync(_url).Result;
        var responsefilter = cl.GetStringAsync(urlfilter).Result;


        JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);
        //JObject jFilter = JObject.Parse(responsefilter);
        var movies = new List<Merge>();
        //var IDx = json["query"]["results"]["div"]["p"][0]["a"]["href"].ToString();
        foreach (var pchild in json["query"]["results"]["div"])
        {
            // ID
            var ID = pchild["p"][0]["a"]["href"].ToString();

            // title
            var titleSt = pchild["p"][0]["a"]["title"];
            var titleStr = titleSt != null ? titleSt.Value<string>() : string.Empty;

            // year
            var releaseDate = pchild["p"][1]["span"][0]["content"];
            string releaseYear = string.Empty;

            DateTime temp;
            if (releaseDate != null && DateTime.TryParse(releaseDate.Value<string>(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out temp))
            {
                releaseYear = temp.Year.ToString();
            }

            // genres
            var genre = pchild["p"][1]["span"][1]["content"];
            var genreArr = genre != null
                            ? genre.Value<string>()
                                .Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Select(st => st.Trim())
                                .ToArray()
                            : new string[0];

            movies.Add(
                new Merge
                {
                    Id = ID.ToString().ToString(),
                    Title = titleStr,
                    Year = releaseYear,
                    Genre = genreArr
                });
        }
```

everything works then when I use a link with exact one Object in the Json array I get an error. for example this link [Link with exactly one object](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.themoviedb.org%2Fsearch%2Fmovie%3Fquery%3DMiss%2BSloane'%20AND%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22info%22%5D'&format=json&callback=)

this is the error I get -

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access child value on
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.'

the way to make it work when it is one object is to remove the loop and directly navigate to the value like this

```
var IDx = json["query"]["results"]["div"]["p"][0]["a"]["href"].ToString();
```

please I need to understand why this is happening and how to do it correctly. thanks

Edit: I can use

```
var query = (Int32)json["query"]["count"];
if (query > 1)
  {}
else
  {}
```

as a hack but I still think I may be doing it wrong.

Comment: You could try checking the length at the start, e.g. `if (json["query"].Length == 1) { var IDx = json["query"]["results"]["div"]["p"][0]["a"]["href"].ToString(); return; }`, or just `else { the foreach loop.. }`.

Comment: I know I can do that but it does not answer the question. is it a bug or am I doing it wrong

Comment: Which line does it occur? Is it the `JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);` line?

Comment: the first line in the for each loop {}

Comment: I suppose you could try adding a breakpoint at the start of the loop to make sure that `pchild` is not getting parsed incorrectly for the second link with 1 item.

Comment: done that. the format is correct

Comment: The single object should be in an array too.

Comment: @Gert I don't understand. every thing is in Jarray so what are you talking about?

Comment: I only see a difference in structure in both Json files using a Json viewer. The "multiple" file has `... div-Array-Object`, the "single" file has `... div-Object`.

Comment: I am away of that which is why I am using if item.Count() > 1 do this but if its equal or less, do that

Comment: @Cody are you using PostMan? Can you please check that the JSON response with a single object is indeed an array, rather than sending an individual object - which may be the case. Perhaps have a look at what is actually being sent out, if you have access to the API source code.

Comment: @BK please click on the links I provided to see the structure. I provided two links